# As Slaughter Crept unto the Sheep

Tags: word, knowledge, rhyme, poetry

> Turn in my lord! Turn in my lord! 
> But water I cannot afford. 
> Some milk is best at your request. 
> Now hide you and get you some rest. 
> But as he sleep, to him she creep, 
> As slaughter crept unto the sheep. 
> Then with a nail, his head impale, 
> So saved the day lady __________.

**What is the lady's name?**

HINT 1:

> The riddle is in reference to an event described in an old famous book.

Comment: This feels like less of a riddle and more like trivia

Comment: I made it too easy then ;-).

Comment: The riddle tag description says that it "gives indirect clues", but this seems to directly describe the lady you're thinking of. Don't get me wrong, the poem is fantastic! It just doesn't seem like a "puzzle"

Comment: @samm82 Perhaps I should remove the riddle tag? It is a knowledge puzzle, and in a old riddle format, but see your point.

Comment: @I suppose to those not very familiar, it presents itself as a puzzle because you would have to use elements of the poem to search old literature to find the answer, hence the knowledge tag.

Comment: Perhaps coincidentally, synagogues the world over read this story today.

Comment: @msh210 I've never been in a synagogue. Interesting to know. I guess all knowledge is common to some circle somewhere.

Comment: @msh210 To be clear, this is an original poem. I'm sure you're not suggesting it is copied from somewhere. It is only in reference to a story familiar to some.

Comment: No, I meant that the _story_ was read yesterday, not that the _poem_ was.

Comment: @msh210 Oh wow! I'm not Jewish, but I am familiar with how they synchronize going thorough to Torah together. That's IS a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lady's name is

> Jael - [Judges 4:18-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges+4%3A18-21&version=NIV)